# ODataServices using ComplexTypes

Tags: java, odata

Is anyone aware of location of any OData service using complex types?There are a lot of services on www.odata.org but they have properties which have SimpleTypes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this one: [http://services.odata.org/v4/DefaultService/$metadata](http://services.odata.org/v4/DefaultService/%24metadata). It's also one of the services provided by the OData.org.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a service based on Enterprise framework (ADO.NET from Database), it will create just that for you.  Search for WCF Data Services examples.  What language are you thinking of using?

Comment: Lastly, http://codenodes.wordpress.com/2011/08/22/return-complex-type-from-odata-wcf-data-service/ :)

Comment: I want to use a service as a Client.I am using java for the same

Comment: Like we have sample service Northwind which we can use.Do we have any other service?(northwind uses only simple types).I want an already created service using Complex Types

Answer (score 0):

There is a complex type Address in this sample: https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v4/ODataCamelCaseSample/